# \ldots produces a square

Tags: punctuation, opentype

Using XeLaTex and OpenType font Goudy Bookletter 1911, the command `\ldots{}` produces ❏ (without shadow).

My question is: **why XeLaTeX does not find automatically a substitute ?**

I guess that this square is meant to replace a character not present in font. With `fontmatrix` I can verify that the character `U+2026` (ellipsis) is not present.

Here is the test case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setromanfont{Goudy Bookletter 1911}

\begin{document}

Trois petits points \ldots{}

\end{document}
```

Now (epilogue question), I modify the test case to use the package `babel`.

Insert this line after the first:

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

and the three dots are produced correctly. Hopefully this is the behavior expected. **But, why this difference ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `xunicode` (that's loaded by the `fontspec` package, in the up-to-date TeX distributions, so it doesn't need to be loaded explicitly) defines `\ldots` to be

```
\char"2026
```

in text mode, while the `french` module for `babel` defines it to give

```
\FBtextellipsis
```

which sets the three dots "by hand", rather than relying on a particular glyph.

You can solve the problem of the missing character by saying

```
\renewcommand{\textellipsis}{.\kern\fontdimen3\font.\kern\fontdimen3\font.\@}
```

in the document preamble (which is what `french` does). Then

```
Three little dots~\ldots
```

will give what's wanted.

Comment: Thank you for this info. Your workaround works well when [french]{babel} is not used. For any font.